# win socket library in vs2010

Tags: c++, sockets, winpcap

I am programming with c++, and using winpcap, I have a error linked in my program, that I don't know where is the problem, and what should I include to resolve this error.I have included this libraries:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <WinSock.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
```

and I have two struct in my code:

```
struct in_addr ip_src;
       struct in_addr ip_dst;
```

after that I used them here:

```
    printf("src address: %s dest address: %s \n", inet_ntoa (ip->ip_src),
 inet_ntoa (ip->ip_dst));
```

but I got this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__inet_ntoa@4 referenced in function _main
```

now where is the problem, which other library should I add?

Comment: `ws2_32.lib`, and note the **Library** section at the bottom of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738564(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: you shouldnt include `winsock` and `winsock2` the two are mutually exclusive. Remove `#include <winsock.h>`

Comment: @WhozCraig based on documentation I found I should have Ws2_32.lib and Ws2_32.dll , how can I understand whether I have them or not? sorry, but I am beginner in vs!!

Comment: @user3210586 did you try to add ws2_32.lib to the library section? You don't have to specify the path. It should work automatically.

Comment: Ws2_32.dll is located in c:\windows\system32.  Ws2_32.lib (the stub library for the DLL) ships with the Windows SDK included with Visual Studio.  Or as @Wimmel said above, it should work automatically when you include that lib in your list of Library imports.

Answer (score 0):

goto to Linker -> Input and type in ws2_32.lib